# How to check if a specific position in a string character or digit or not by using isdigit, isalpha

Tags: python, string, if-statement, isalpha

I wanna check a specific position in my string if it a character or not using isalpha the same by isdigit

I tried Using startswith and endswith but it didn’t work because I need to check only the start and the end of the string

Comment: Do you know how to select a specific character, such as `your_string[i]`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the i-th character of your string like this: `ith_character = string[i]` (starting with zero, of course). So, for example, if you'd like to check whether the third character is a digit, you'd write: `string[2].isdigit()`